# INSERT INTO multiple rows with subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to `INSERT INTO` by more than one value at a time, I did this by doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col_1,col_2,col_3)
SELECT col_1, col2, (SELECT col3 FROM table_3)
FROM table_2
```

But `col3` from `table_3` is a datetime format, while `col3` from `table_1` needs an `integer` value. I did this by doing the following:

```
CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10),(SELECT col3 FROM table_3),112)AS int)
```

When I run this I get a `more than one result in a subquery` error. I have really no idea whatsoever on how to fix this. Hopefully you do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Having more than one result is not because of the CASTING. Even if you run the `SELECT col3 FROM table_3` individually, you'll still have several rows. You need to add filtes so you get only the required data

Comment: All col3 from table_3 will be selected. You are missing the WHERE clause.

Comment: But I need all data in `table_1`. Field by field. I do not need to make exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col_1,col_2,col_3)
SELECT col_1, col2, (CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10),(SELECT top 1 col3 FROM table_3),112)AS int))
FROM table_2
```

You need to use **top 1** to select 1 row

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but there are multiple datetimes in `table_3.col_3`. So when I would use `SELECT TOP 1` then I would get one value on every field in `table_1.col_3`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the error says it all. You have to limit the inner query somehow with WHERE condition, with TOP or with MAX(col3) for example. Depends WHICH col3 you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join table_2 to table_3. Not sure what your database structure is, but it should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col_1,col_2,col_3)
SELECT t2.col_1, t2.col2, t3.col3 
FROM table_2 t2
INNER JOIN table_3 t3 on t3.t2id = t2.id
```

The alternative is to use TOP 1, to just return 1 record in the sub-query - but I would not recommend this as it may not be the value you want:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col_1,col_2,col_3)
SELECT col_1, col2, (SELECT top 1 col3 FROM table_3)
FROM table_2
```

Comment: This seems like it could be working. I still have some questions, though. The datetime value is within `table_3` whilst everything else in within `table_2`. So that `INNER JOIN` statement doesn't work then. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: you need to show your real columns and table names in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to prepare your data :

```
;WITH MyData (col1, col2, col3)
AS
(
    SELECT col_1, col2, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10),(col3),112)AS int)
    FROM table_2 JOIN table_3 ON <join condition>
)
INSERT INTO table_1(col_1,col_2,col_3)
SELECT col_1, col2, col3
FROM MyData
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try below query :

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col_1,col_2,col_3)
SELECT col_1, col2, isnull((SELECT TOP 1 cast(col3 as int) FROM table_3),0)
FROM table_2
```

Comment: I don't want the first result. I want the first result to be in the first field, the second one to be in the second field and so on.