# Xpath Syntax correct?

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlunit

I need to test a program on site, so I can´t test it until I am at the site. I want to know if the following Xpath is the right one. I have read the syntax on http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp but I am still not sure if this is right.

If there is a button in a tablerow `<tr>` and in the `<tr>` there is a `<td>`. Within the `<td>` is a `<button value = 'button'>` specified.
I think the Xpath would be:

```
"/html/body//table//tr//td//button[@value=['button']"
```

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The correct XPath would most probably be

```
//button[@value = 'button' and ancestor::td]
```

This would also find `button` elements inside `td` if they are not immediate children of the `td` element. If you know that the `button` element is always a direct child of `td`, you can have an expression like

```
//td/button[@value = 'button']
```

or

```
//button[@value = 'button' and parent::td]
```

You do not need `//` in so many places and you do not need to start the expression at `html`. Having `//` (the `descendant-or-self::` axis) might or might not impact on performance, depending on the application.

Also, as pointed out by John 30 secs before my answer, there is a superfluous bracket in your expression.

Comment: Thanks for your response, really appreciate it! I hope it works now!

Comment: @user3208216 You are welcome. Please consider _accepting_ an answer to your question. Actually, not only to this question, but all of your questions, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759512/insert-into-multiple-rows-with-subquery).

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing right bracket, so no. The second left bracket shouldn't be there.

```
/html/body//table//tr//td//button[@value='button']
```

By the way, double `//` selectors are slow and should be avoided when possible. I'd recommend

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/button[@value='button']
```

or

```
//td/button[@value='button']
```

instead. It's a given that a `<td>` will be inside a table so no need for the extra `table`, `tr`, and `td` element searches if you're using `//` anyways.

Comment: Careful, last two examples fail for `<td><div><button value='button'/></div></td>`.